# Problem in getting right result for select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, solr

I have implemented [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for my search results. 
Now I want to display results based on sort criteria.
In my user interface I created a select box for user to give select criteria. But the problem is each time user selects, the results are appended in the webpage (for example if I got 5 results in first select then I got 9 results from 2nd select where in second select I expect only 4)
I want to display only those 4 results.
What can be the problem?

For code please look at [Problem in getting right result for select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677042/problem-in-getting-right-result-for-select-box)

Comment: Not very clear problem - are the extra results coming from your server or from your client code. Do you have `html+=` or `.append()` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code from the other thread indicates that it is repeatedly adding tables to the bottom of #result, on this line:

`$("#result").append(html);`

You need to replace the results each time to get the behavior you want:

`$("#result").html(html);`